# Get product original & small images by product id

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to get all magento product images

```
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app(); 

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);  //some ID    

$productMediaConfig = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config');

$baseImageUrl  = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($product->getImage());
$smallImageUrl = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($product->getSmallImage());
$thumbnailUrl  = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($product->getThumbnail());

echo 'Base URL      : '. $baseImageUrl.'<br />';
echo 'small URl     : '. $smallImageUrl.'<br />';
echo 'thumbnail URl : '. $thumbnailUrl.'<br />';
```

The output for `Base, small and thumbnail images` is the same image 
So how can I get all other product images?

Answer (score 4):

You can get all images by `getMediaGalleryImages()` this function. ex.

```
foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
        preload[]=$image->getUrl();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems a copy/paste issue. Check the single quotes in your code

```
$productMediaConfig = Mage::getModel(‘catalog/product_media_config’);
```

Should be...

```
$productMediaConfig = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config');
```

Comment: Yes, it was a copy/paste issue. Sorry. but the output for `Base , Small and thumbnail images` was the same image. I am still can't get all product images ?!

Comment: I have been edited the question to be more specific of the current issue.